# How to add a horizontal line above the button upon button click

Tags: button, onclick

I am currently working with a bootstrap menu that has a dropdown element upon button click.

[image]

I want to make the horizontal line appear upon click but can't do so with border on a click function as this pushes the content down.

I tried with a pseudo element `:before`, however have not seen any solutions on how to add a pseudo element with a on click function in JS.

If anyone has any solutions please let me know.

Comment: If your menu item is focused while it's being clicked on, you can add a :focus and put the horizontal line on the focus?

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to add border-bottom:1px solid #000 like to a div on button click?
Maybe we need to see the html as well.  Border bottom wont push the content down.  But if the css has no element that makes sense, then just position the horizontal line absolute.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#yourdivclass").css("border-bottom", "1px solid #000");
});
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/mila732/pen/jxPYKQ Here is a link to my codepen where I have it working in the active state. However, I want the yellow line on top to remain there upon press of the button until the user clicks on another button or on the button again. Ultimately this will be for a dropdown navigation so its opening and closing the dropdown. If you have any solves for this, please let me know!